# Why was my app rejected from Apple for a content rating that's identical to other similar apps?

Tags: ios, app-store

This is the third time we've submitted our messaging app to the Apple App Store, and this time we got a very upsetting response:

> The rating you’ve selected, 4+, is inconsistent with the content of your app. Since your application includes content and features involving user-generated information and picture sharing, it should be rated appropriately for this subject.

Not only is this cryptic, but it is *completely* inconsistent with what's already out there in the store.  All of the top 5 messaging apps have ratings at 4+, and every single one of them have user-generated content.  On top of that, I used the "rating form" that allows you to select items to determine what rating system you're in.  It selected 4+.

My question is this: what do you do to combat inconsistent requests from the app store?  I submitted an appeal, but I'm unhappy that I actually have to do this in the first place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about AppStore approval.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third-party tech support issue that readers have no control over.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's app review policies and not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is this: what do you guys do to combat ridiculous inconsistent requests from the app store? I submitted an appeal, but I'm furious that I actually have to do this in the first place.

Welcome to the world of iOS developers. This is the state of the art. And believe it or not, it was worse in the past.

I had a few apps rejected which did exactly the same as other apps. Fighting against it is useless most of the time, im my opinion. Apple is Apple. And will ever be.

Making insanely much money shows them, they are on the right track.

Comment: In this case it seems that is is an issue of preventing the abuse of children.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the inconsistent portion, that will buy you nothing. Instead concentrate on why the app was rejected: "includes content and features involving user-generated information and picture sharing". This is a valid concern on Apple's part: Apple has decided to rate content by age and as such they have a responsibility to attempt as best as possible to provide such protections.

Note as an example that any app that allows a user to browse to an address of their choosing must have a high age rating.

An app such as your is open to mis-abuse in many ways, think about it.

The solution is either raise the age or provide some mechanism to prevent abuse.